# PDO error on the updated PHP 5.3.6 from 5.2.x

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Actualy my server updated PHP to 5.3.6 from 5.2.x. After this- all my mysql connections failed. I catch such PDO error
             **Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**
Also checked in php.ini file value of the **pdo_mysql.default_socket** which is **/tmp/mysql.sock**

Host service told me to repair my mysql DB passwords. But it didn't help.
Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hehe, nice support ;) This has absolutely nothing to do with the passwords. PDO_MySQL communicates under linux via sockets with the mysql-server. First of all find out, where is the socket now. (Sorry, but I dont know how :X)

If you have access to the `php.ini`, change

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

If you dont have access to it, change the the instanciation of the pdo-object like described under  [PDO_MySQL Connection](http://php.net/pdo-mysql.connection)

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=/path/to/mysql.sock;dbname=testdb');
```

You probably must change/add some settings here.

Comment: Thank You very much.  So have to find where is the socket together with hosting support :).